# Can't access any ASPX files on my new Win Server 2008 SP2 install, enabled folder permissions/added users but still no go

Tags: windows-server-2008

Just installed Windows Server 2008 SP2

Installed IIS, ASP.NET and other necessary roles.

For my site folder I edit the permission to include
users: Network Service and a bunch of other IIS user names
a long with that Internet guest one. Fiddled around with the
application pool (Load user profile:True , Identity Network Service etc.
Also only change I made from the default fresh install settings 
was installing the .Net 4 framework.

I can view regular html files etc. But should I want to make use of ASP.NET and access an aspx page, I get the following:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

When running a settings test I get:

*The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.*

Any ideas?

THanks..

Comment: Where is your directory located ? Put it under inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer I know is the solution, but here are my suggestions:

First, have you mapped the IIS default web site to the folder containing your site?

Second, check your basic apppool settings, and make sure it's set to use .Net 2.0.  It'll be 2.0 even if you're using a later version, like 4.0.

Barring that, make a new folder in wwwroot and map the default web site to that. Do not mess with the permissions. Then, make a new apppool, don't fiddle with it's settings, and assign that to the default web site. Point here is that you shouldn't have to mess with any of those settings: IIS  will take care of that and the permissions.

Final thought, if that doesn't help: check your isapi filter mappings to make sure it knows what to do with .aspx. That should have been set up by default as well, but it's worth a look at that point.